# xcode 5 can't add the gpuimage project to my xcode project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import, gpuimage

my problem is, that I'll add the GPUImage.xcodeproj file to my xcode project.
But if I'll do this this window does not appear:

[image]

So I can't add the GPUImage Target Dependencie to my project. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/) to manage your dependencies, it's simple to use and to update.

IMHO, it also makes your project cleaner.

If you still want to install it manually, make sure you have followed this "tutorial":

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#adding-the-framework-to-your-ios-project

Otherwise, use cocoaPods! :

1- open `terminal` and install cocoapods with `gem` :

> $> sudo gem install cocoapods

2- go into your project folder:

> $> pod init
>
> // it will create a Podfile

3- Edit the Podfile and copy past:

```
platform :ios, "7.0"

pod 'GPUImage', '~> 0.1.0'

// save and close the file
```

4- install dependencies:

> $> pod install
>
> // on a successful install enter:
>
> $> open projectName.xcworkspace/
>
> // it will open your xcode project with your dependencies already set up

5- Import GPUImage in ViewController

6- Enjoy!